# Modelling Vizux M400 - topology question

Tags: modeling, topology

I would be grateful for advice on how to build a topology for this part of the Vuzix M400 glasses. I have already re-modeled them from scratch three times, and each time it turns out not exactly what is needed.

Here is the reference:

[image]
[image]

From this side, the topology seems to look kind of ok (correct me if I'm wrong).

[image]

But from this side, it looks strange and does not allow me to achieve the desired shape.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like that: Begin with a 16 vertex cylinder, boolean the bottom with another cylinder:

[image]

Apply the *Boolean*, give it a *Mirror* on Y, fill the hole and edit the topology:

[image]

Scale down the top on X to make it narrow, keep the front flat, draw a curve to prepare the circular shape:

[image]

Extrude on the left:

[image]

Tilt the extrusion and so on:

[image]

Comment: Beautiful solution, thank you so much!

Comment: What do you mean by Mirror on Y? I applied Boolean modifier and added Mirror modifier, but nothing happens.

Comment: cut it in half and give it a Mirror modifier, as it looks symmetrical on Y

Comment: Got it, thanks.